# Do Derby databases have a limit

Tags: relational-database, derby

Does a derby database have a limit to how many times you can query it (over its lifetime)? I know that a Derby database stores the transactions made on it so that ROLLBACK can be called and restore the database to a previous state. However, the question still exists on whether this would limit the number of queries/changes made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. Slightly longer answer: You can only rollback transactions that have not yet committed. The number of uncommitted transactions you can have is only limited by the size of the log which is only limited by your file system.

Of course, testing the limits of software in this way is usually not a good idea, and with lots of uncommitted transactions you risk losing a lot of data in the event of a crash (software or hardware). Best practice is to commit transactions as soon as you can as this will make your system more robust, perform better and reduce contention (an open transaction holds locks on elements of your db which will put restrictions on concurrent access).

Comment: and since, according to this, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit , I don't have to worry about uncommitted transactions because I don't mess with the commit setting! Thank you so much for your quick response; it led to me alleviating my fears about making "too many" transactions to a Derby database over time!